# How to exclude io.undertow.request package from the logging in wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, undertow

I am getting following error logs related to **io.undertow.request** package.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:153)
at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.doWrap(SslConduit.java:874)
at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.write(SslConduit.java:379)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:247)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:588)
at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:120)
at io.undertow.conduits.DeflatingStreamSinkConduit.performFlushIfRequired(DeflatingStreamSinkConduit.java:418)
at io.undertow.conduits.DeflatingStreamSinkConduit.flush(DeflatingStreamSinkConduit.java:348)
at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.flush(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:162)
at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.flush(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:119)
at org.xnio.channels.Channels.flushBlocking(Channels.java:63)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:605)
```

In this case, it is not necessary to see those errors in my wildfly log. I need to exclude this package from the logging.Is there anyway that I can make a configuration for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want any logging from `io.undertow.request` then add below tag in standalone-*.xml file in logging subsystem:

```
          <logger category="io.undertow.request">
            <level name="OFF"/>
        </logger>
```

Comment: Or with CLI: `/subsystem=logging/logger=io.undertow.request:add(level=ERROR)` or whichever level you'd like to see.